# Keyboard shortcut Ctrl+' does not work in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 (17.7.6) on Windows 10, and trying to bind the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+'` to `Edit.ToggleLineComment`. I can successfully bind the key combination to the command. But when I'm trying to use it nothing happens. If I bind the same command to `Ctrl+Shift+'` it works just fine. I'm using a Swedish keyboard. How can I fix this?

[image]